# Suppose $A^4 = 2A^2$. Show $(I-A^2) = (I-A^2)^{-1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm completely stumped on this one. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here. For typesetting equations please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Compute and simplify $(I-A^2)(I-A^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$(I - A^2)(I - A^2) = I - 2A^2 + A^4; \tag 1$

with

$A^4 = 2A^2, \tag 2$

(1) reduces to

$(I - A^2)(I - A^2) = I, \tag 3$

which shows that

$(I - A^2) = (I - A^2)^{-1}. \tag 4$